# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'signup.test.Robots.props.history.location.state'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The toggle button in my react file doesn't send any data to firebase. The code returns this error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'signup.test.Robots.props.history.location.state'.

I have defined all my props too. Please help me if you find a mistake.

the buttons:

```
 <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect mt-2 lg:w-1/3">
                                                

                                                    <label class="btn btn-default mx-1  rounded " >
                                                        <div class="bizcontent  py-2" id="bizcontent">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Space" autocomplete="off" value="Space" hidden 
                                                            checked={this.state.isSpace}
                                                            onChange={this.onChangeSpace} />
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                                            <p>Space</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <label class="btn btn-default mx-1 rounded">
                                                        <div class="bizcontent py-2 "  >
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Robots" autocomplete="off" value="Robots" hidden 
                                                             checked={this.state.Robots}
                                                             onChange={this.onChangeRobots}/>
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                                            <p>Robots</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </label>
                                                    
                                                    <label class="btn btn-default mx-1 rounded">
                                                        <div class="bizcontent  py-2">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Magic" autocomplete="off" value="Magic" hidden 
                                                            checked={this.state.isMagic}
                                                            onChange={this.onChangeMagic} />
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-lg"></span>
                                                            <p>Magic tricks</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </label></div>
```

the states and props:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            age: '',
            email: '',
            phone_number: '',
            redirect: false,
            showAlert: false,
            alertMessage: '',
            isSpace: '',
            Robots: '',
            Magic: '',
            
        }
    
        this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
        this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
        this.onAgeChange = this.onAgeChange.bind(this);
        this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.onNumberChange = this.onNumberChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeSpace = this.onChangeSpace.bind(this);
        this.onChangeMagic = this.onChangeMagic.bind(this);
        this.onChangeRobots = this.onChangeRobots.bind(this);




    }

    
    onChangeSpace = () => {
        console.log("onChanges");
        this.setState(initialState => ({
          isSpace: !initialState.isSpace,
        }));
      }
    
      onChangeMagic = () => {
        console.log("onChanges");
        this.setState((currentState) => ({
            Magic: currentState.Magic, 
        }));
      }
      onChangeRobots = () => {
        console.log("onChanges");
        this.setState((currentState) => ({
            Robots: currentState.Robots, 
        }));
      }
```

Sending data to firebase:

```
    import firebase from '../firebase.js';

export function register(email, name, age, phone_number, isSpace, Robots, Magic, isArt, isMusic, _this) {

    firebase.database().ref('/signup/' + name).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() === null || snapshot.val() === undefined) {
            firebase.database().ref('signup/' + name).set({
                name: name,
                age: age,
                email: email,
                phone_number: phone_number,
                isSpace: isSpace,
                Robots: Robots,
                Magic: Magic,
                
            });
            
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Could you log the `Robots` property content before sending it to firebase ?

Comment: yes, I tried using console.log but nothing prints on the console (seems states arent getting changed?)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that you passed an invalid value to `set()`.  Read it carefully:

> Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'signup.test.Robots.props.history.location.state'

It's saying that the value with the path `signup.test.Robots.props.history.location.state` is undefined.  So, it sounds like whatever you passed as `Robots` contains a nested property `props.history.location.state` which is undefined.  You will have to do some debugging to figure out why that is.